# User anonymity while submitting data in smart contract

Tags: transactions, security, privacy, anonymity

I've written a smart contract, that is a crowd sensing system. Where post posting a task user view that task and if they have what I'm asking for/and meet the task requirements they submit certain data.

My question here is, how can I ensure that the users that submit the data are kept anonymous? No one can link the data submitted to a particular user.

Is this doable, and any help with techniques I could use to achieve so?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is doable because every action that changes the state of the blockchain needs to know the address of the sender to make a transaction and that transaction is public for everybody.

The only way I can think of is making a proxy contract which uses [eip1167](http://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1167):  to the proxy contract and then to the contract which lets the user send transactions to that proxy contract and let it forward to the destination contract but even then somebody can still trace back which address send the transaction initially, it just adds a small layer of obscuration.

Comment: Thanks for your help, will check this out however, as per your advise it will still not achieve anonymity emm okay.
Could you kindly give me an example of how such a system would work if not too much trouble?